# Capture RatingBar Click

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I seem to have a problem with catching my ratingbar click.  The ratings bar is showing up just fine and has the default value.  The only problem is that I cannot change any values or it isn't enabled.  I have tried numerous different things (e.g. enabling in the layout, building it entirely in java).  None of them seem to have an impact.  Here is my latest incarnation of the ratings bar.  I must be doing something stooopid to not be able capture the click.

Java Code:

```
  RatingBar showRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.showRatingBar);
    showRatingBar.setEnabled(true);
    showRatingBar.setClickable(true);
    showRatingBar.setRating(0);
    showRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
            System.out.println("showRating.buildRatingBar:  " +rating);
            ratingBar.setRating(rating);

        }});
    showRatingBar.refreshDrawableState();
```

Layout:

```
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showQualityLabel"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/show_rating_label"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#E6E6E6"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/showRatingBar"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="5"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="0"
            android:stepSize="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Craig

Answer (score 34, accepted):

setOnClickListener() not working is that RatingBar overrides onTouchEvent()  and never let View take care of it, so View#performClick() is never called (which would have called the OnClickListener).

derive from RatingBar and override onTouchEvent()

```
ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                     float touchPositionX = event.getX();
                     float width = ratingBar.getWidth();
                     float starsf = (touchPositionX / width) * 5.0f;
                     int stars = (int)starsf + 1;
                     ratingBar.setRating(stars);

                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf("test"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
                     v.setPressed(false);
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setPressed(true);
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    v.setPressed(false);
                }




                return true;
            }});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck.  I still cannot get anything to recognize my clicks or any change in the ratings.  Strange?!?!

Comment: I have found a way to do that, try it :)

Comment: Nice!!!  That was exactly it.  The key was the onTouch function.  Thank you very much.